# Javamail Body does not appear when together with attachment

Tags: java, android-studio, jakarta-mail

So I have the problem with the Javamail where if I send an attachment in the mail the body disappears. When I don't send an attachment with the mail i can just see the body.

My GMailSender.java:

```
public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
        _multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    }


    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
    {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception
    {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
        message.setSubject(subject);

        message.setText(body);
        message.setDataHandler(handler);
        if(_multipart.getCount() > 0)
            message.setContent(_multipart);
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
        else
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
        Transport.send(message);

    }

    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception
    {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }
```

My MainActivity.java

```
        Button bt_send = findViewById(R.id.Alert);
        bt_send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                BackgroundMail bm = new BackgroundMail(context);
                bm.setGmailUserName("***@gmail.com");
                bm.setGmailPassword("******");
                bm.setMailTo(to);
                bm.setFormSubject(value + " DOC/" + mTvResult.getText().toString());
                bm.setFormBody("Document Nummer:\n" + mTvResult.getText().toString() + "\n \nDocument Type:\n" + value);
                if (images.size() > 0) {
                    for (Object file : images) {
                        bm.setAttachment(file.toString());
                    }
                }
                bm.setSendingMessage("Loading...");
                bm.setSendingMessageSuccess("The mail has been sent successfully.");
                bm.send();
            }
        });
```

So how can i add an attachment while still being able to see the body itself?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you copied GMailSender from someone else.  You should start by fixing all these [common mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).

You never call the addAttachment method.  (Note that you could replace that method with the [MimeBodyPart.attachFile](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#attachFile-java.io.File-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method).  Please remember to post the code that you're *actually* using.

The key insight that you're missing is that for a multipart message the main body part needs to be the first body part in the multipart.  Your call to `Message.setContent(_multipart);` overwrites the message content that was set by your call to `message.setDataHandler(handler);`, which also overwrote the content set by your call to `message.setText(body);`.

Instead of setting that content on the message, you need to create another MimeBodyPart, set the content on that MimeBodyPart, and then add that MimeBodyPart as the first part of the multipart.